# How to generate a list of all possible strings from shortest to longest

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I need to generate an infinite list of strings using numbers and letters.  The first string should simply be "a", then "b" through to "z", then "0" through to "9", then "aa", "ab" etc.

I can easily generate the ones with one character, but then it gets more complicated.

Comment: The fun but confusing way: ``[1..] >>= (`replicateM` "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz012346789")``

Comment: Note that this would technically be impossible. You could only generate all finite strings (or all finite strings plus almost none infinite lists interspersed.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So, suppose we already had this list of all possible strings:

```
 allStrings :: [String]
 allStrings = ...
```

Given `allStrings`, how could we create another list of all possible strings?

```
 alsoAllStrings :: [String]
```

Let's look at each possible string as a single character prefix, and a string suffix

```
 alsoAllStrings = [ c : s
```

The string suffix is either the empty string or a member of the list of all possible strings.

```
                  | s <- "" : allStrings
```

The single character prefix is in `'a'` thru `'z'` or `'0'` thru `'9'`.

```
                  , c <- ['a'..'z'] ++ ['0'..'9']
                  ]
```

(this is using list comprehensions - we could also do the same using `concatMap`:

```
alsoAllStrings = concatMap (\s -> map (:s) $ ['a'..'z'] ++ ['0'..'9']) $ "" : allStrings
```

)

Now let's go back to the original question.  How do we find `allStrings`?

In most languages, we couldn't - it's an infinite list of strings, the program would never finish.  But since Haskell is lazy, it's cool with generating only as much of `allStrings` as we actually use.

One surprising thing that this lets us do is we can define `allStrings` in terms of `alsoAllStrings`.

```
 allStrings = alsoAllStrings
```

Or, more likely, in terms of itself.

```
 allStrings = [ c : s | s <- "" : allStrings, c <- ['a'..'z'] ++ ['0'..'9'] ]
```

This is called corecursive data - data that is defined in terms of itself.
Try it out in ghci:

```
 ghci> let allStrings = [ c : s | s <- "": allStrings, c <- ['a'..'z'] ++ ['0'..'9'] ]
 ghci> take 100 allStrings
 ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","aa","ba","ca","da","ea","fa","ga","ha","ia","ja","ka","la","ma","na","oa","pa","qa","ra","sa","ta","ua","va","wa","xa","ya","za","0a","1a","2a","3a","4a","5a","6a","7a","8a","9a","ab","bb","cb","db","eb","fb","gb","hb","ib","jb","kb","lb","mb","nb","ob","pb","qb","rb","sb","tb","ub","vb","wb","xb","yb","zb","0b","1b"]
```

The reason it works (and doesn't just loop infinitely) is that it defines part of itself before it uses itself.  The first elements we include in `allStrings` are the single character extensions to the empty string `""`.  So by the time we start iterating through the elements of `allStrings` to use as suffixes, the first couple elements `allStrings` are already defined and available.  And the more suffixes we process, the more elements of `allStrings` are defined and available to use as suffixes.

It's very similar to a common haskellism of defining the fibonacci numbers corecursively:

```
 fibs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

Don't be surprised if corecursion takes a while to wrap your head around. It's worth the effort to understand, though.

Answer (score 7):

This can be done by getting all combinations for strings of length 1,2,3..., then concating them all together.

I started with a combos function, which returned all list of strings with the given characters and the given length:

```
combos :: [Char] -> Int -> [String]
```

The fist case is simple, just turn the input chars into lists:

```
combos chars 1 = map (:[]) chars
```

The next case we want 'aa', 'ab', 'ac'... to 'zx', 'zy', 'zz'. This is the same as `map ("a" ++) ["a", "b", "c"...] ++ map ("b" ++) ["a","b",...]` right up to `map ("z" ++) ["a","b"...]`.

`["a".."z"]` is the same as `combos chars 1`. That function can be written as:

```
combos chars 2 = concatMap (\front -> map (front ++) (combos chars 1)) (combos chars 1)
```

The next case we want 'aaa', 'aab', ... 'zzy', 'zzz'. This is actually very similar to combos 2, except we are using as the front `combos chars 2` instead of `combos chars 1`:

```
combos chars 3 = concatMap (\front -> map (front ++) (combos chars 1)) (combos chars 2)
```

(note the `combos chars 1` doesn't change, that just gives us the list of one character strings to append to the end.)

See the pattern here? It can now be generalized for all n as:

```
combos :: [Char] -> Int -> [String]
combos chars 1 = map (:[]) chars
combos chars n = concatMap (\front -> map (front ++) (combos chars 1)) $ combos chars (n - 1)
```

Finally, to get the infinite list of all strings, just concat all the results of combos together with the required characters and all lengths:

```
allCombos :: [String]
allCombos = concatMap (combos (['a'..'z'] ++ ['0'..'9'])) [1..]
```

Example output:

```
> take 100 allCombos
["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","aa","ab","ac","ad","ae","af","ag","ah","ai","aj","ak","al","am","an","ao","ap","aq","ar","as","at","au","av","aw","ax","ay","az","a0","a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6","a7","a8","a9","ba","bb","bc","bd","be","bf","bg","bh","bi","bj","bk","bl","bm","bn","bo","bp","bq","br","bs","bt","bu","bv","bw","bx","by","bz","b0","b1"]
```

Comment: And given that `combos` ≡ `replicateM` and `concatMap` ≡ `(=<<)`, you get the solution in my comment :)

Comment: Working with the monad functions with the list monad is something I haven't mastered yet - I'm a bit read only with that code (I understand how they work, but don't usually think of writing it like that). I still find `filterM (const [True, False])` one of the most amazing pieces of code in any language.

Comment: @nanothief: You should play around with them--there is a lot of fun to be had. If you want a nice challenge, write a simple Prolog interpreter. (Prolog relies on backtracking and nondeterminism, which is exactly what lists model.)

Answer (score 2):

I came up with the following solution:

```
-- Gives us the concatenated cartesian product of two lists of strings
strCartProd :: [String] -> [String] -> [String]
strCartProd xs ys = [x ++ y | x <- xs, y <- ys]

-- Create initial list of strings (map chars to 1-char strings)
s :: [String]
s = map (:[]) $ ['a'..'z'] ++ ['0'..'9']

-- Iterate and concatenate the resulting lists
result :: [String]
result = id =<< iterate (strCartProd s) [""]
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done simply by a predefined function replicateM from (Control.Monad).

```
string = concatMap (\n -> replicateM n (['a'..'z']++['0'..'9'])) [1..]
```