# How to create all possible combinations of these two lists?

Tags: list, haskell, combinations, combinatorics

I'd like to take from these two lists to create a list of all combinations, where each combination is also a list.

E.g.

Given two lists: `[1,2,3]` and `[True, False]`

Combinations:

```
[(1, False), (2, False), (3, False)]
[(1, False), (2, False), (3, True )]
[(1, False), (2, True ), (3, False)]
[(1, True ), (2, False), (3, False)]
[(1, False), (2, True ), (3, True )]
[(1, True ), (2, False), (3, True )]
[(1, True ), (2, True ), (3, False)]
[(1, True ), (2, True ), (3, True )]
```

There should be `2^n` combinations where `n` is the number of numbers.

EDIT:

Tried to do the following:

```
[(n, b) | n <- [1,2,3], b <- [True, False]]
(,) <$> [1,2,3] <*> [True, False]
```

Comment: In your example the numbers are constant, so you could do something like this: `[ [(1,x),(2,y),(3,z)] | x <- [True, False], y <- [True, False], z <- [True, False] ]`

Comment: The numbers are variable in this case. Only thing that's constant is `[True, False]`

Comment: I think I said that wrong, what I mean is in the example it's always `1,2,3` in that order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can avoid using `length`, which might be unsafe, since the list can have infinite length. By using recursion or a foldr pattern, we avoid that:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}

allComb :: [b] -> [a] -> [[(a,b)]]
allComb vs = go
    where go [] = [[]]
          go (x:xs) = (:) <$> map (x,) vs <*> go xs
```

or with a foldr-pattern in a one-liner:

```
allComb :: [b] -> [a] -> [[(a,b)]]
allComb vs = foldr (\x -> ((:) <$> map (x,) vs <*>)) [[]]
```

For example:

```
Prelude> allComb [False, True] [1,2,3]
[[(1,False),(2,False),(3,False)],[(1,False),(2,False),(3,True)],[(1,False),(2,True),(3,False)],[(1,False),(2,True),(3,True)],[(1,True),(2,False),(3,False)],[(1,True),(2,False),(3,True)],[(1,True),(2,True),(3,False)],[(1,True),(2,True),(3,True)]]
```

The above approach will not work on infinite lists, although we can, given the first list contains at least one element, slightly alter the code, to generate the first element of the result: a list that zips all the elements in the second list with that item. I leave that as an exercise.

Comment: No matter how smart you are, you will fail to correctly implement this on infinite lists.  Thanks, Cantor!

Comment: @luqui On the other hand, it should be possible to do something for infinite lists that has the property that 1. first I choose the (infinite) result list 2. then you choose your favorite finite prefix length 3. then I can show that all the labelings for prefixes of that length appear at finite indices in my result list. That should be good enough for most computations -- at least the ones you expect to finish eventually!

Answer (score 2):

Your desired output can be produced by defining

```
foo :: [a] -> [b] -> [[(a, b)]]
foo nums bools =
    map (zip nums) . sequence $ replicate (length nums) bools
  =
    let n = length nums 
    in 
        [ zip nums bs | bs <- sequence $ replicate n bools]
```

and calling

```
foo [1,2,3] [False, True]
```

That call is equivalent to

```
    let nums = [1,2,3]
        bools = [False, True]
        n = 3
    in 
        [ zip nums bs | bs <- sequence $ replicate n bools]
      =
        [ zip [1,2,3] bs | bs <- sequence $ replicate 3 [False, True]]
      =
        [ zip [1,2,3] (b:bs) | b  <- [False, True]
                             , bs <- sequence $ replicate 2 [False, True]]
      =
        [ zip [1,2,3] (b:c:bs) | b  <- [False, True]
                               , c  <- [False, True]
                               , bs <- sequence $ replicate 1 [False, True]]
      =
        [ zip [1,2,3] (b:c:d:bs) | b  <- [False, True]
                                 , c  <- [False, True]
                                 , d  <- [False, True]
                                 , bs <- sequence $ replicate 0 [False, True] ]
      =
        [ zip [1,2,3] (b:c:d:bs) | b  <- [False, True]
                                 , c  <- [False, True]
                                 , d  <- [False, True]
                                 , bs <- sequence [] ]
      =
        [ zip [1,2,3] (b:c:d:bs) | b  <- [False, True]
                                 , c  <- [False, True]
                                 , d  <- [False, True]
                                 , bs <- [[]] ]
      =
        [ zip [1,2,3] (b:c:d:[]) | b  <- [False, True]
                                 , c  <- [False, True]
                                 , d  <- [False, True] ]
```

i.e.

```
        [ zip [1,2,3] [b,c,d]    | b  <- [False, True]
                                 , c  <- [False, True]
                                 , d  <- [False, True] ]
```

and if evaluate this last expression, we also get the same result.

Filling up the three spaces with each possible combination of the two available  values is like having all possible functions from 3 spaces to 2 values, whatever those spaces and values are.

Mathematicians write this function as *2<sup>3</sup>*, and indeed, we get `2^3 = 8` outputs.

*edit:* the `sequence ... replicate` combo is actually just reimplementing another built-in, `replicateM`:

```
foo ns bs = map (zip ns) (replicateM (length ns) bs)
```

because `replicateM n a` is just like `sequence (replicate n a)`, but without actually building the intermediate list.

For the [pointfree](/questions/tagged/pointfree) aficionados, we can thus have

```
foo ns    =  map (zip ns) . replicateM (length ns)
          =  (.) ((map . zip) ns) ((replicateM . length) ns)
          =  ((.) . map . zip <*> replicateM . length)   ns
```

i.e.

```
foo       =  (.) . map . zip <*> replicateM . length
```

Comment: Oh, `sequence` was what I wanted. I couldn't figure out how to do that. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

This can't be the most straightforward or most efficient answer.

But using the technique from [How to generate a list of all possible strings from shortest to longest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542313/how-to-generate-a-list-of-all-possible-strings-from-shortest-to-longest) we can generate a list of all possible Boolean sequences. We take the ones that are the same length as the second list and then zip them with that list.

```
allBoolPermutations :: Int -> [[Bool]]
allBoolPermutations n = takeWhile (\l -> length l == n) 
                      $ dropWhile (\l -> length l < n) 
                      $ allBools
  where
    allBools = [ c : s | s <- []:allBools, c <- [True, False]] 


zipWithBoolPermutations :: [a] -> [[(a, Bool)]]
zipWithBoolPermutations someList = map (zip someList) 
                                       (allBoolPermutations (length someList))
```

Then `zipWithBoolPermutations [1,2,3]` should give you what you want.

Comment: *solving the more general problem and then getting your smaller problem solved for free* principle, huh. also, if we inline the dropWhile and the takeWhile, we end up with that zip list comprehension equivalent of the sequence. :) but you probably wanted the general code, for arbitrary `n`...

Comment: @WillNess It's a good way to answer homework questions, I think: useful and true, but you still have to think in order to reduce it back to the original problem; if you just copy/paste it the instructor will have a reasonable idea you didn't do it yourself.

Comment: @amalloy there was a discussion about homeworks few years back on meta, when the tag was "burninated", and the verdict as far as I understood it was, *"just answer it, regardless"*. I don't know what the current consensus is.

Comment: Yes, well-asked homework questions should be answered. But I don't think it's against the spirit of the thing to answer them in a way that leaves fingerprints.

Answer (score 2):

Nice and short:

```
traverse ((<$> [True, False]) . (,)) [1,2,3]
```

Or less pointfree, but perhaps more understandable:

```
traverse (\x -> [(x,True), (x,False)]) [1,2,3]
```

The inner function (`(<$> [True, False]) . (,)` or `\x -> [(x,True), (x,False)]`) takes each element such as `1` and turns it into `[(1,True),(1,False)]`. If you think of `traverse f` as being `sequence . fmap f`, then the `fmap f` part means do that function to each thing in the list (yielding `[[(1,True),(1,False)],[(2,True),(2,False)],[(3,True),(3,False)]]`), and the `sequence` part means combine them with the List applicative (which models non-determinism) to create all possible combinations (yielding `[[(1,True),(2,True),(3,True)],[(1,True),(2,True),(3,False)],[(1,True),(2,False),(3,True)],[(1,True),(2,False),(3,False)],[(1,False),(2,True),(3,True)],[(1,False),(2,True),(3,False)],[(1,False),(2,False),(3,True)],[(1,False),(2,False),(3,False)]]`).

Comment: `sequence [map (x ,) [False, True] | x <- [1,2,3]]`, then. :) seems to be it. nice!

Comment: it actually goes to the core of what (List) Monad is, with `liftA2 (,) xs ys = join [fmap (x ,) ys | x <- xs]` (and `xs <|> ys = join [xs, ys]`).